# Update-safe translating of single text string in plugin

Tags: plugins, translation

I'm trying to change an English text string in a plugin that has the following structure:

```
├── language
│   ├── albdesign-wc-donations-sq.mo
│   ├── albdesign-wc-donations-sq.po
│   └── default.pot
└── woocommerce_donations_on_cart.php
```

I'm using only English on the website I installed the plugin, so I could also just edit the English text strings in woocommerce_donations_on_cart.php, but I would prefer a solution that is update-safe.

I read about putting translations in wp-content/languages/plugins/ with the same name of the file(s), but as there are no English .mo/.po files that would probably not work.

So I used the code styling project plugin to create an empty albdesign-wc-donations-en_US.po and added my custom translation like so

```
msgid "Add a donation to your order"
msgstr "Add a donation"
```

but that doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

to use the file `wp-content/languages/plugins/albdesign-wc-donations-uu_UU.mo` in the plugin, it has to be declared like that :

```
load_plugin_textdomain("albdesign-wc-donations"); // search in wp-content/languages/plugins/
// search in the plugin files if not found in wp-content/languages/plugins/
load_plugin_textdomain("albdesign-wc-donations", FALSE, plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "languages/");
```

is it's not the case, you can create another plugin to correct that loading of the translations files